# Interface with method GetInstance<T>() in .Net?

Tags: .net

I am not sure if there is any interface already exist in .Net like this:

```
public interface IController {
      T GetInstance<T>(string name) where T: class;
}
```

Basically, this interface contains a method to get instance of T by name/key. IControler is an arbitrator name I use here. It may be something like IFactory, ICreator, or something I don't know. The method name may not exactly like this(GetInstance). I think this may be a generic method which can be used to get/query an instance from a container, parent or controller.

If there is one, I would not need to create one(just adding a reference); otherwise, I'll define one.

Comment: If it existed, it would more likely be a generic interface, rather than a non-generic one with a generic method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this sounds exactly like an IoC container. You might want to look at the [common service locator](http://www.codeplex.com/CommonServiceLocator)

Comment: This is very nice link. The interface of IServiceLocator provides more generic interfaces for my case. I like their methods as well, better than my. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This problem has generally been solved by container-managed repositories, which are at the heart of Dependency Injection frameworks like [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity/), [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) and [NInject](http://ninject.org/).

Comment: This is exactly my case. The parent class contains a container which needs to be initialized and then I need to the container to get instances by this interface or outside and nested classes.

Comment: @David.Chu.ca: It sounds like you need dependency injection to do your type resolution, then!